# How do I create an Azure ServiceBus SaS Token with Publish Only Rights?

Tags: azure, token, servicebus

I need to create a SaS token programmatically for a service bus with Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus 3.X nuget package to work with a .NET standard library.

I can successfully create and use a token to subscribe and publish to Service Bus. 
I don't see an option where I can limit the token to be able to only publish.

```
TokenProvider td = SharedAccessSignatureTokenProvider.CreateSharedAccessSignatureTokenProvider(policyName, policyKey, expireTimeSpan);
var token = await td.GetTokenAsync($"{path}{topic}", expireTimeSpan);
```

I would like to limit the rights on this token to be able to only publish to the topic, but not subscribe.  Is this possible and if so how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this possible and if so how can I do this?

If I understand correctly, you need to create a policy with [send] right. And then use the policyName and generated key to create the sas token.

[image]

The rights conferred by the policy rule can be a combination of:

> - **'Send'** - Confers the right to send messages to the entity
> - **'Listen'** - Confers the right to listen (relay) or receive (queue, subscriptions) and all related message handling
> - **'Manage'** - Confers the right to manage the topology of the namespace, including creating and deleting entities

For more information, please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-sas#shared-access-authorization-policies).

**Update:**

We could use the [Microsoft.Azure.Management.ServiceBus.Fluent](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent/) to create the policy.

```
var authorizationRuleName = "xxx"; //policy name
var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromFile(@"D:\Tom\Documents\azureCred.txt");
var restClient = RestClient.Configure().WithEnvironment(AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud)
                .WithCredentials(credentials)
                .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.Basic)
                .Build();
System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken = new System.Threading.CancellationToken();
ServiceBusManagementClient client = new ServiceBusManagementClient(restClient)
            {
                SubscriptionId = subscriptionId
            };
List<AccessRights?> list = new List<AccessRights?> { AccessRights.Send};
//create policy
SharedAccessAuthorizationRuleInner result = client.Namespaces.CreateOrUpdateAuthorizationRuleAsync(resourceGroupName, nameSpace, authorizationRuleName, list, cancellationToken).Result;
//get key
var key = client.Namespaces.ListKeysAsync(resourceGroupName, nameSpace, authorizationRuleName).Result?.PrimaryKey;
```

How to create the azureCred file, please refer to this [document](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net/blob/master/AUTH.md#using-an-authentication-file).

Comment: Thanks my goal is to do this programmatically